# Python 3 - Socket SMTP timeout after sending username to Gmail

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, gmail

Unsure if this has been asked before, but I can't find any solutions that seem to work.

I'm running this on a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.6.6.

For a school assignment, I've been tasked with coding a Python script that connects via SMTP and the socket library to Gmail and sends a sample message. Here's my code in its entirety below, as I'm unsure what's causing its issue:

```
import socket, ssl, base64

# Initialize variables
msg = "\r\n I love computer networks!"
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"
username = '***' # My email address went here
password = '***' # I put my password here

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 465

# Send and get response
def send_com(in_string, response_num):

    # Only send content if provided, and if in string format, convert to bytes
    if in_string != '':
        if type(in_string) == str: in_string = in_string.encode()
        ssl_clientSocket.send(in_string)

    # Get response
    recv = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()

    # If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not  '250', we have a problem
    if recv[:3] != response_num and response_num != '':
        print (recv[:3] + ' reply not received from server.')
    else:
        print (recv)

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket) 
ssl_clientSocket.connect((mailserver, port))

send_com('', '220')                                     # SMTP server initialization
send_com('HELO Alice\r\n', '250')                       # Send HELO command and print server response.
send_com('AUTH LOGIN\r\n', '334')                       # Authenticate mail server

print ("Username: " + base64.b64encode(username.encode()).decode())
print ("Password: " + base64.b64encode(password.encode()).decode() + "\n")

send_com(base64.b64encode(username.encode()), '334')    # Send username
send_com(base64.b64encode(password.encode()), '235')    # Sned password
send_com('MAIL From: <' + username + '>\r\n', '250')    # Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
send_com('MAIL From: <' + username + '>\r\n', '250')    # Send RCPT TO command and print server response.
send_com('DATA\r\n', '250')                             # Send DATA command and print server response.

send_com(msg, '')       # Send message data.
send_com(endmsg, '')    # Message ends with a single period.

send_com('QUIT\r\n', '221') # Send QUIT command and get server response.

#recv5 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(I1024).decode()
```

**I know that it hangs after sending my encoded username to Google's servers.** All of the code above it appears to execute and return the appropriate server responses without any issues. However, once it reaches the command that sends the encoded username, the program hangs until I close the terminal.

Comment: why don't you use `smtplib`?

Comment: I would, but my professor specifically told me not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
send_com('AUTH LOGIN\r\n', '334')                       # Authenticate mail server

print ("Username: " + base64.b64encode(username.encode()).decode())
print ("Password: " + base64.b64encode(password.encode()).decode() + "\n")

send_com(base64.b64encode(username.encode()), '334')    # Send username
send_com(base64.b64encode(password.encode()), '235')    # Sned password
```

It looks like you have wrong understanding of how the LOGIN authentication methods works. Basically it looks like this:

```
>  AUTH LOGIN
 < 334 base64("Username:")
>  base64(your_username)
 < 334 base64("Password:")
>  base64(your_password)
```

Thus, you don't send any `"Username: " + base64(your_password)` to the server but just the base64 encoded password - with a new line at the end of course. This means above code should more look like this:

```
send_com('AUTH LOGIN\r\n', '334')                       # Authenticate mail server

send_com(base64.b64encode(username.encode()) + "\r\n", '334')    # Send username
send_com(base64.b64encode(password.encode()) + "\r\n", '235')    # Send password
```

The two lines where you've send username and password are gone but left are the other lines where you've send username and password again - only that in these cases a new line is also send.

This fixed it will no longer by stuck at the original place.

It will complain later since you send to `MAIL FROM` commands instead a `MAIL FROM` followed by a `RCPT TO`. And it will get stuck on `send_com(msg, '')` since your `send_com` function tries to read from the server even though you don't expect anything back. And the code will also complain that some status codes returned from the server are unlike what you expect. But once this is fixed the mail will be send successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response!